# Generate data from a coin flipping experiment

Tags: python, statistics, coin-flipping

I have a coin and the coin has memory. i.e. the last flip impacts the probability of heads on this flip. How do I write code to generate data from this process? Specifically, from this process, I want to be able to generate n=1000 data points.

```
P(H | H_{-1}) != P(H | T_{-1}) #probability of heads given heads in last flip is not equal to probability of heads given tails in last flip
P(T | H_{-1}) != P(T | T_{-1}) #probability of tails given heads in last flip is not equal to probability of tails given tails in last flip
```

`{-1} represents last flip`

```
Assume P( H | H in last flip ) = 0.75
P( H | T in last flip ) = 0.30
```

Also, assume that the first flip of a coin has equal probability of landing a heads or tails.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you please brief me about what this two expressions mean?

Comment: @CutePanda: Yes, I just explained those two expressions in plain English words in the updated post.

Comment: How do you determine the probability of heads for a flip at any given time? Is there a specific numerical value? It might be easier for you to explain if you show an example with three flips and the probabilities for each of them.

Comment: @AkilanManivannan: I have updated the post with some imaginary values.

Comment: I just modified my code to fit your example. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @AkilanManivannan: Yes, your answer is gold! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a skeleton that you can use for your experiment.

```
import random

def flip(last_flip):
    if last_flip == "H":
        #INSERT LOGIC FOR PROBABILITY IF PREVIOUS FLIP WAS HEADS
        heads_probability = 0.75
    elif last_flip == "T":
        #INSERT LOGIC FOR PROBABILITY IF PREVIOUS FLIP WAS TAILS
        heads_probability = 0.30
    else:
        heads_probability = 0.5

    tails_probability = 1-heads_probability
    flip = random.choices(["H", "T"], weights = (heads_probability, tails_probability))[0]

    return flip


flips = []
lastFlip = None
for n in range(1000):
    newFlip = flip(lastFlip)
    flips.append(newFlip)
    lastFlip = newFlip
```

This uses the `random.choices` function to select heads or tails with uneven probabilities. The `flip` function takes the previous flip as an input and calculates the new probability of the coin toss. You will need to fill this part in with the logic that you are using for your experiment (where the comments are).

The main part of the code flips the coin and stores the result in an array. For the next trial, it uses the previous flip as input for the `flip` function discussed earlier.

Comment: This answer is gold! Thank you so much for such a clear explanation! This works for me!